# Add an existing SQLite3 database to Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a SQLite database already existing locally that I need to access in my Swift application.  As I was developing, I was just referencing the copy on my computer and everything worked fine.  Now I need to include that database; I assumed it would be as simple as dragging it into the Supporting Files and referencing it there.  That was a little trickier than I thought, and after researching I found this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String
    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("members.sqlite3")
    println(databasePath)
    memberDatabase = FMDatabase(path: databasePath)
    if memberDatabase == nil {
        println("error finding database")
    } else {
        if memberDatabase!.open(){
            println("database is ready")
        }
    }
```

It prints "database is ready" like expected, but when I run the existing queries that worked before, I get `no such table: member_data`. I looked at the file that the `databasePath` specifies and indeed, it's empty.  What am I missing?

Comment: The only way to get "canned" data into your app is through the bundle.  But if you simply place the DB file in the bundle and access it there it will be essentially read-only.  It must be copied to a read/write directory by a "first time through" routine.

Comment: Ok... a lot of words there I don't know, but I'll start Googling.  For what it's worth, read-only would be just fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested whether or not I can write to this database (I don't need to for my app) but after including the file in "Supporting Files" and adding it to the target app, this worked:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("members", ofType:"sqlite3")
memberDatabase = FMDatabase(path: path)
```

(Note: I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb))